# Gpio pins not changing states (rpi4; xbian)

Tags: gpio, pi-4, xbian

I'm trying to control my GPIO pins on a fresh xbian install on my rasperry pi 4b

gpiozero and RPi.gpio are installed

The python script I use appears to be working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time

import warnings
from gpiozero import OutputDevice


SLEEP_INTERVAL = 5  # (seconds) How often we check the core temperature.
GPIO_PIN = 17  # Which GPIO pin you're using to control the fan.




if __name__ == '__main__':

    fan = OutputDevice(GPIO_PIN)
    print("got fan")
    fan.on()
    print("turned it on")
```

But if I afterwards request the value with

```
fan = OutputDevice(GPIO_PIN)
    if fan.value:
        print("ON")
    else:
        print("OFF")
```

I am always getting "Off".

**UPDATE**: The reason for this was that gpiozero resets state on exit. (I was still using code that assumed gpio states were kept)

Maybe it helps: also getting this error:

```
sudo cat /sys/class/gpio/export
cat: /sys/class/gpio/export: Input/output error
```

Also, I have in my boot/config.txt tried to manually set 17 to output and high. On boot it gets enabled. But it quickly turns off again.

Any way to set this gpio pin to high would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard of xbian but assuming it supports /sys/gpiomem you are mixing incompatible I/O systems (sysfs is deprecated). Try reading the gpiozero documentation and follow the tutorials.

Comment: Frankly the code you listed is incomplete and unconventional. You say "but afterwards" we don't know what that means. gpiozero resets pin state on exit.

Comment: Ah, that appears to be the issue! Thanks!